# R: Compare data.table and pass variable while respecting key

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables:

```
original <- data.frame(id = c(rep("RE01",5),rep("RE02",5)),date.time = head(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-11-01 01:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2015-11-05 01:00:00"),60*60*10),10))
compare <- data.frame(id = c("RE01","RE02"),seq = c(1,2),start = as.POSIXct(c("2015-11-01 20:00:00","2015-11-04 08:00:00")),end = as.POSIXct(c("2015-11-02 08:00:00","2015-11-04 20:00:00")))
setDT(original)
setDT(compare)
```

I would like to check the date in each row of `original` and see if it lies between the start and finish dates of `compare` whilst respecting the `id`. If it does lie between the two elements, a variable should be passed to `original` (`compare$diff.seq`). The output should look like this:

```
    original
     id           date.time diff.seq
1  RE01 2015-11-01 01:00:00       NA
2  RE01 2015-11-01 11:00:00       NA
3  RE01 2015-11-01 21:00:00        1
4  RE01 2015-11-02 07:00:00        1
5  RE01 2015-11-02 17:00:00       NA
6  RE02 2015-11-03 03:00:00       NA
7  RE02 2015-11-03 13:00:00       NA
8  RE02 2015-11-03 23:00:00       NA
9  RE02 2015-11-04 09:00:00        2
10 RE02 2015-11-04 19:00:00        2
```

I've been reading [the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) and SO for hours and trying "on", "by" and so on.. without any success. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at `foverlaps(...)` in data.table 1.9.6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, this is very straight forward using `data.table::foverlaps`

You basically have to create an additional column in the `original` data set in order to set join boundaries, then key the two data sets by the columns you want to join on and then simply run `forverlas` and select the desired columns

```
original[, end := date.time]
setkey(original, id, date.time, end)
setkey(compare, id, start, end)
foverlaps(original, compare)[, .(id, date.time, seq)]
#       id           date.time seq
#  1: RE01 2015-11-01 01:00:00  NA
#  2: RE01 2015-11-01 11:00:00  NA
#  3: RE01 2015-11-01 21:00:00   1
#  4: RE01 2015-11-02 07:00:00   1
#  5: RE01 2015-11-02 17:00:00  NA
#  6: RE02 2015-11-03 03:00:00  NA
#  7: RE02 2015-11-03 13:00:00  NA
#  8: RE02 2015-11-03 23:00:00  NA
#  9: RE02 2015-11-04 09:00:00   2
# 10: RE02 2015-11-04 19:00:00   2
```

Alternatively, you can run `foverlaps` the other way around and then just update the `original` data set *by reference* while selecting the correct rows to update

```
indx <- foverlaps(compare, original, which = TRUE)
original[indx$yid, diff.seq := indx$xid]
original
#       id           date.time                 end diff.seq
#  1: RE01 2015-11-01 01:00:00 2015-11-01 01:00:00       NA
#  2: RE01 2015-11-01 11:00:00 2015-11-01 11:00:00       NA
#  3: RE01 2015-11-01 21:00:00 2015-11-01 21:00:00        1
#  4: RE01 2015-11-02 07:00:00 2015-11-02 07:00:00        1
#  5: RE01 2015-11-02 17:00:00 2015-11-02 17:00:00       NA
#  6: RE02 2015-11-03 03:00:00 2015-11-03 03:00:00       NA
#  7: RE02 2015-11-03 13:00:00 2015-11-03 13:00:00       NA
#  8: RE02 2015-11-03 23:00:00 2015-11-03 23:00:00       NA
#  9: RE02 2015-11-04 09:00:00 2015-11-04 09:00:00        2
# 10: RE02 2015-11-04 19:00:00 2015-11-04 19:00:00        2
```